# how to access oracle storedprocedure from from asp.net mvc +nhibernate

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate

how to call a oracle database storedprocedure from asp.net mvc  using nhibernate and how to use sys_refcursor to display a data in view pages give me sample application . thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are [some](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/1e5c71502dd547f0/a7908ea36bed6a5e) evidences that NHibernate [does not support](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2398761) stored procedures using `sys_refcursor`.

---

UPDATE: It seems that this has been [fixed in 2.1.1.GA](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-847?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel)